# CSS navbar issues

Tags: css

I have a header with logo on the left and links on the right.
On smaller screens (such as a tablet) links doesn't fit in one line.
When using float:left for the logo, and float:right for the links, all the links fall to a new line, which is not the desired behaviour.
When using display: table-cell for both divs, the link area background-color spreads beyond the link area, which is not the desired behaviour too.
I'm stucked on what css formula is the better solution.
I need to keep all the links on the right of the logo, but the background-color should not spread beyond the link area.

Here is a fiddle with 2 examples, one with a lot of links (2 lines) and one with less links (1 line):
http://jsfiddle.net/ARauS/

```
#header {
    display: table;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    width: 100%;
}
#header #logo {
    #float:left;
    display: table-cell;
}
#header #links {
    #float:right;
    background-color: silver;
    text-align: right;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 0; /* remove whitespace between menu itens*/
}
#header #links a {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 8pt;
    line-height: 18pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6a6a6a;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#header #links a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#header #links a.personal {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfcfc, #e7e7e7);
}
```

Comment: Well you just need to make it responsive so i works for bi and smaller screens

Comment: Could you use twitter-bootstrap or some other framework helping you to add responsive structure easily?